# Javascript Prototype String - accessing string value

Tags: javascript, string, count, prototype

Im trying to Add a few methods to the Javascript String Object. one of the main methods im trying to add is a substring count function

```
String.prototype.substring_count = function(delimiter){
    return {THIS IS WHAT I NEED THE STRING FOR}.split(delimiter).length;
}
```

Where do you access the string in the String object?

Answer (score 2):

Use `this`. In the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), it is mentioned

> If the method is on an object's prototype chain, this refers to the
>   object the method was called on

in this case, the string itself

```js
String.prototype.substring_count = function(delimiter){
    return this.split(delimiter).length;
}

console.log('test,123'.substring_count(','));
```

Comment: I thought it was that, I have used prototyping before but i thought it had a certain variable within the String Object thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohnHudson, yes, `this` in a prototype method will refer to the object, in this case,the string itself